# how to verify Counter value is greater than 9 in yaml files

Tags: if-statement, yaml, counter, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
variables:
  VER_MAJOR: 4
  VER_MINOR: 6
  VER_BUGFIX: 1
  REVISION: $[counter(format('{0}.${1}.${2}', variables['VER_MAJOR'], variables['VER_MINOR'], variables['VER_BUGFIX']), 10)]
  SVN_REVISION: $(REVISION)
  MAJOR: "$(VER_MAJOR)"
  ${{ if gt(variables['SVN_REVISION'], 9) }}:
    VER_BUILD_NUM: "$(VER_BUGFIX)$(VER_BUGFIX)$(SVN_REVISION)"
  ${{ else }}:
    VER_BUILD_NUM: "$(VER_BUGFIX)$(VER_BUGFIX)$(VER_BUGFIX)$(SVN_REVISION)"
```

How to verify that the counter is greater than 9? Thanks